# Unable to Update InlineFormset in Django with CBV

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

```
class PreChildrenView(CreateView):
    model = PreDealDetails2
    template_name = 'cam_app/children_form.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('forms_app:deal-entering')
    session_initial = 'children_'

    def get_initial(self,**kwargs):
        initial = super(PreChildrenView, self).get_initial(**kwargs)
        initial['deal_id'] = self.request.session['deal_id']
        return initial

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(PreChildrenView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['childrens'] = ChildrenFormSet(self.request.POST)
            print('post')
        else:
            print('get')
            data['childrens'] = ChildrenFormSet()
            data['childrens'].extra = 5
            data['info'] = 'Children Details'

        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('wwwww')
        context = self.get_context_data()
        childrens = context['childrens']

        if form.is_valid():
            pass
        if childrens.is_valid():
            count = 0
            self.object = form.save()
            childrens.instance = self.object
            childrens.save()

            self.request.session[self.session_initial + 'children_count'] = count

            self.request.session['valid_children'] = True
            messages.success(self.request, 'Successfully filled Children Details')
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
        else:
            return super(PreChildrenView, self).form_invalid(form)


class UpdatePreChildrenView(UpdateView):
    model = PreDealDetails2
    template_name = 'cam_app/children_form.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('forms_app:deal-entering')
    session_initial = 'children_'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return PreDealDetails2(deal_id = self.request.session['deal_id'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(UpdatePreChildrenView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            a = PreDealDetails2.objects.get(deal_id = self.request.session['deal_id'])
            data['childrens'] = ChildrenFormSet(self.request.POST)
            print('post')
        else:
            print('get')
            data['childrens'] = ChildrenFormSet(instance=self.object)
            data['childrens'].extra = 5
            data['info'] = 'Children Details'

        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('update valid')
        context = self.get_context_data()
        childrens = context['childrens']

        if form.is_valid():
            print('wejri')
            self.object =form.save()
            if childrens.is_valid():
                childrens.instance = self.object
                childrens.save()

                count = 0
                self.request.session[self.session_initial + 'children_count'] = count

                self.request.session['valid_children'] = True
                messages.success(self.request, 'Successfully filled Children Details')
                return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
            else:
                return super(UpdatePreChildrenView, self).form_invalid(form)
        else:
            print('sfeief')


class PreChildrenRedirectView(RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self):
        flag = 0
        try:
            PreDealDetails2.objects.get(deal_id=self.request.session['deal_id'])
            flag = 1
        except:
            pass
        if flag == 1:
            return reverse("cam_app:update-prechildren-view")
        else:
            return reverse("cam_app:create-prechildren-view")
```

I am using above code to enter details to form and later update form.
CreateView is working fine and saving data.
UpdateView is displaying data. When i try to save updateview it is showing following error :-
[image]

Code Flow :-
First **PreChildrenRedirectView** is called. It checks if data already exist or not. If it does then Updateview is called and if it doesnot exist then Createview is called.

I am not using slug. Instead i am using get_object in Updateview. Let me know what is causing problem or how to solve the error.

## Update

I have changed the forms.py to remove the error in child. But Deal Id is still showing error. I am also attaching the forms.py below

```
class ChildrenForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PreChildrenDetails
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChildrenForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['deal_id'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False

    def clean(self):
        print('wow')
        pass

ChildrenFormSet = inlineformset_factory(PreDealDetails2,PreChildrenDetails, form=ChildrenForm, fields = '__all__', extra=1)
```

Below is screenshot of error after updating
[image]